# How to control the precedence of nested floating elements wrapping in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a design with two columns, which are both floating divs.  Each of those, in turn, contains a set of divs with label and and input, also both floating.

As I narrow my browser window with the simple sample below, the outer blocks wrap first (in Chrome and FF), and then eventually the inner blocks wrap.  While this is fine in many situations, there are also scenarios where I would prefer that the inner blocks wrap first, to preserve the concept of two major columns as long as possible.

Is there any way for me to control which set of divs wraps first?

```
<div style="float:left">
    <div style="clear:left;padding:1em">
        <div style="float:left;width:10em">Name 1</div>
        <input style="float:left;width:12em" />
    </div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;padding:1em">
    <div style="clear:left">
        <div style="float:left;width:10em">Name 2</div>
        <input style="float:left;width:12em" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the only way is to use something else instead of all these nested float. It's better for you than trying to fix this.

Comment: If you want to use columns, use columns.

Comment: I believe that columns are meant for "flow" content, not fixed content. I have found that specifying a width such as 50% for the outer divs will cause the inner divs to wrap first, but then I need a media query to force the outer divs to wrap at some point